# How can I reorder pandas dataframe rows based on values in a column in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe like below:

| strategy | duration | sales | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TP1 | 22 | 2000 | 1800 |
| TP2 | 10 | 3000 | 1500 |
| TP3 | 5 | 1000 | 1200 |

I would like to order it using the strategy column values.

This is what I have tried:

```
order = ['TP3', 'TP1', 'TP2']
df = df.set_index('strategy').reindex(order).reset_index()
```

When I run this code, I get Nan values as in below:

```
Strategy    duration   Sales    Revenue
TP3         Nan        Nan      Nan
TP1         22         2000     1800
TP2         Nan        Nan      Nan
```

Important note: I am doing this over multiple files, reading the files pd.read_csv(file) and trying the above. Some files will have only 2 strategies not all 3.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the output of `df['strategy'].unique()`?

Comment: they are unique values. so the o/p would be TP1, TP2, TP3

Comment: That's not why I asked, if you have NaNs this means that your TP1 is missing, maybe due to a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below,
order = ['TP3', 'TP1', 'TP2']

```
df['strategy'] = pd.Categorical(df['strategy'], categories=order, ordered=True)

# Sort the DataFrame based on the 'strategy' column
df = df.sort_values('strategy').reset_index(drop=True)
```